# Why is my validation function not working (to validate if user input is an integer within range)

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, java.util.scanner, do-while

I'm trying to make a validation function, but as I tried to make the code "neater" by putting everything inside the function, the code stops working.
This is my original code that works :

```
static int readValidInt(Scanner in, String prompt, int min,  int max){
    while(!in.hasNextInt()) { //Makes sure that user inputs an Integer, not String, double, etc
        System.out.println("Sorry, only numbers in integer form is allowed. Please enter your choice as an integer between 1 and 4");
        in.next();
    }
    int a = in.nextInt();
    if ( a >= min && a <= max) {
        System.out.println("you have chosen board"+ a );
        return a;   
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        return 0;
    }
    //in main, use a do while loop to keep this running until the input is right(until a becomes something that is not 0)
}

public static void main (String args[]) {
    int validinput;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("WELCOME TO CS300 PEG SOLITAIR GAME !" + "\n====================================");
    System.out.println("Board Style Menu");
    System.out.println("\t1) Cross \n \t2) Circle \n \t3) Triangle \n\t3) Simple T"); //Prints out the 4 options of boards, spacing all of them with \t and \n
    System.out.println("Choose a board style");
    do {
        validinput = readValidInt(input, "Bruh that's not valid", 1, 4);
    }
    while (validinput == 0);
}
```

This is the output :
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpQEE.png]

This is the code of the version where I tried to take the do while loop out of main:

```
public static int readValidInt(Scanner in, String prompt, int min,  int max){   
    int checker;
    int a;

    while(!in.hasNextInt()) { //Makes sure that user inputs an Integer, not String, double, etc
        System.out.println("Sorry, only numbers in integer form is allowed. Please enter your choice as an integer between 1 and 4");
        in.next();
    }
    do {
         a = in.nextInt();
            if ( a >= min && a <= max) {
                    System.out.println("you have chosen board"+ a );
                    checker = 1;
                    return a;   

                }
        else {
            System.out.println(prompt);
            checker = 0;
            return 0;
        }   
    }while (checker==0);
}

public static void main (String args[]) {
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("WELCOME TO CS300 PEG SOLITssssAIR GAME !" + "\n====================================");
    System.out.println("Board Style Menu");
    System.out.println("\t1) Cross \n \t2) Circle \n \t3) Triangle \n\t4) Simple T"); //Prints out the 4 options of boards, spacing all of them with \t and \n
    System.out.println("Choose a board style");
    
    readValidInt(input, "Bruh that's not valid", 1, 4);
}
```

This is the output of the one that doesn't work (it terminates without giving me another attempt):
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/flOXj.png]

Comment: `do { ... }while (checker==0);` this never loops, it returns after the first iteration every time. Both paths of the `if` return a value, so it will never get to the 2nd iteration.

Comment: When you tell your program to "return", then it will do that, no matter if there is a loop wrapped around that code or not.

Comment: Can't believe I learned 8 months of Java and did not realize that

Comment: I just found another flaw of this program after I fix the do-while and was hoping you guys can help me with it : If I input 345, the program will say that number is not allowed since it is not between 1 and 4, but since it is an integer, it has already gone pass the while(!in.hasNextInt()) loop, meaning if after I input a String/double *after* my first attempt of 345, it becomes an exception. Is there a way to prevent this? I was thinking of putting the while loop inside the do-block (it made sense in my brain but that would just become another do while loop)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using try catch so the function won't be too clunky

Comment: I can't solve this by making a function for the while(!in.hasNextInt()) loop, and calling it inside the do block because we can only use a fixed amount of functions(assigned by my lecturer) in this assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `if-else` branch, you always `return` (which will exit the method) on the first loop iteration no matter what.  You will never loop.

To fix this, you want to set the value of `checker` to the value you attempted to `return` before and then `return checker` *after* the loop:

```
public static int readValidInt(Scanner in, String prompt, int min, int max) {
    int checker;
    int a;

    while (!in.hasNextInt()) { // Makes sure that user inputs an Integer, not String, double, etc
        System.out.println(
                "Sorry, only numbers in integer form is allowed. Please enter your choice as an integer between 1 and 4");
        in.next();
    }
    do {
        a = in.nextInt();
        if (a >= min && a <= max) {
            System.out.println("you have chosen board" + a);
            checker = a;

        } else {
            System.out.println(prompt);
            checker = 0;
        }
    } while (checker == 0);
    
    return checker;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Choose a board style
five
Sorry, only numbers in integer form is allowed. Please enter your choice as an integer between 1 and 4
5
Bruh that's not valid
1
you have chosen board1
```